# How to push values with Navigator and recieve them?

Tags: android, flutter, navigator

I need know how to push values from a screen to another screen with Navigators, because I searched and and didn't understand how it works to push and recieve data and values, or what is the best way to share values to of a screen to another screen.

**UPDATE**

Look I want to push the `var videoPath` value to the previuos screen after finishing the `_stopvideoRecording()` Future function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer this official doc of Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

```
Code to send data to new Screen 

 Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),
      ),
    );
```

Second Page/Receiving page

```
 class TodosScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  //requiring the list of todos
  TodosScreen({Key key, @required this.todos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos'),
      ),
      //passing in the ListView.builder
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(todos[index].title)
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So this is right ? 
`Navigator.pop(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => New_Aya(),
          settings: RouteSettings(
            arguments: videoPath,
          ),
        ),
      );`

Comment: No, refer official doc

Comment: refered and did as it said but didn't work, it gave me null, Is there a better way ?

Comment: the problem that I don't want to make a list, it is just a var.

Comment: How did u put todo: method inside the DetailPage() ?

Comment: bro just remove list..use String , Int as per your requirement

Comment: todo is just named..change it to as per your widget name

Comment: but there is one problem.

Comment: when I create the videoPath in the recieving page, it says must be intialized.